# Nothing appearing the console when Decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, decode

I'm trying to play around with a COVID dataset from Github (link in code below) but when I run the code nothing appears in the console. There are no errors appearing.

Can anyone advise on whats wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
struct country: Decodable {
    var location: String
    var new_cases: Double
    var people_fully_vaccinated: Double
}

func getJSON(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/68c39808d445fe90b1fe3d57b93ad9be20f796d2/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.json") else{
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard  let data = data else{
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode([country].self, from: data) else{
            return
        }
        let countries = decodedData
        for country in countries{
            print (country.location)
        }
    }.resume()
}

getJSON()
```

Comment: The main issue with the code is that you are ignoring any errors by using try?  so you are missing vital information. Use `try` inside a do/catch and print the error in the catch clause

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var location:  String
    var new_cases: Double?  // make it optional as it has some objects with nil 
    var people_fully_vaccinated: Double?  // make it optional as it has some objects with nil 
}
```

With

```
do {
    let res = try decoder.decode([String:Root].self, from: data)
    let locations = Array(res.values).map { $0.location }
    print(locations) 
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for printing out the variables included within the struct. How would I then print(country.location)?